# Disable TypeScript mismatch in ng-packagr

Tags: angular-cli, ng-packagr

In an Angular CLI project, when using an unsupported version of TypeScript you may get the following warning:

```
@angular/compiler-cli@6.1.0 requires typescript@'>=X.X.X <Y.Y.Y' but Z.Z.Z was found instead.
Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.
```

It is possible to disable the TypeScript mismatch warning for the default project with the following command:

```
ng config cli.warnings.typescriptMismatch false
```

Now, when building an Angular library, `ng-packagr` throws this warning as an error, even with the `typescriptMismatch` setting set to `false`. Is it possible to temporarily disable this error? It is understood that this should not be done in a production environment, but it may be helpful when debugging issues that may be caused by TypeScript. The following [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850063/rootdir-is-expected-to-contain-all-source-files) serves as an example use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `disableTypeScriptVersionCheck` under `angularCompilerOptions` In your tsconfig.

Comment: For anyone interested, I did not find this option in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#angular-compiler-options) but it is listed in [this source file](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.1.x/packages/compiler-cli/src/transformers/api.ts#L137).

Comment: @SamHerrmann I'd offer you a coffee (you need to come to Italy hahaha)! Thank you!

Comment: Just an update the [link](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#disabletypescriptversioncheck) related to disableTypeScriptVersionCheck