# Typescript Invalid 'reference' directive syntax

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm-build

I'm setting up a typescript-nodejs project in my local environment in which I'm facing an issue when I try to perform the

> npm run build-ts

It throws the following error:

> node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:40:1 - error TS1084: Invalid
> 'reference' directive syntax.

```
/// <reference> lib="esnext.asynciterable" />
```

> node_modules/@types/superagent/index.d.ts:17:1 - error TS1084: Invalid
> 'reference' directive syntax.

```
/// <reference lib="dom" />
```

[CLI error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SroP.png)

**Dependencies**

```
"@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
"@types/helmet": "0.0.47",
"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
"dont-sniff-mimetype": "^1.1.0",
"helmet": "^3.23.3",
"helmet-csp": "^2.10.0",
"strict-transport-security": "^0.2.2",
"1.1.1": "^1.0.0",
"@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
"@types/cors": "^2.8.4",
"@types/lokijs": "^1.5.2",
"@types/mathjs": "^4.4.1",
"@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.9",
"@types/passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.33",
"async": "^2.6.0",
"aws-sdk": "^2.252.1",
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.3",
"bluebird": "^3.5.1",
"body-parser": "^1.18.2",
"class-validator": "^0.8.5",
"compression": "^1.7.1",
"connect-mongo": "^2.0.0",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"cors": "^2.8.4",
"csv-parse": "^3.0.0",
"dotenv": "^4.0.0",
"errorhandler": "^1.5.0",
"express": "^4.16.2",
"express-csv": "^0.6.0",
"express-fileupload": "^1.1.6-alpha.6",
"express-flash": "0.0.2",
"express-session": "^1.15.6",
"express-validator": "^4.3.0",
"fbgraph": "^1.4.1",
"fuse.js": "^3.2.1",
"http-status-codes": "^1.3.0",
"json2csv": "^4.2.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"lokijs": "^1.5.5",
"lusca": "^1.5.2",
"mathjs": "^5.2.0",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"mongoose": "^4.13.0",
"node-schedule": "^1.3.0",
"nodemailer": "^4.7.0",
"passport": "^0.4.0",
"passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
"passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"qs": "^6.5.2",
"rand-token": "^0.4.0",
"request": "^2.83.0",
"request-promise": "^4.2.2",
"uuid": "^3.3.2",
"webshot": "^0.18.0",
"winston": "^2.4.0",
"xml2js": "^0.4.19"
```

***DevDependencies:***

```
"@types/async": "^3.2.3",
"@types/bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.30",
"@types/bluebird": "^3.5.32",
"@types/body-parser": "^1.16.8",
"@types/compression": "^0.0.35",
"@types/connect-mongo": "^0.0.35",
"@types/dotenv": "^4.0.2",
"@types/errorhandler": "^0.0.32",
"@types/express": "^4.11.1",
"@types/express-session": "^1.15.8",
"@types/jest": "^22.1.3",
"@types/jquery": "^3.2.17",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.91",
"@types/lusca": "^1.5.0",
"@types/mongodb": "^3.5.26",
"@types/mongoose": "^4.7.34",
"@types/morgan": "^1.7.35",
"@types/node": "^9.4.6",
"@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.0",
"@types/passport": "^0.4.3",
"@types/passport-facebook": "^2.1.7",
"@types/passport-local": "^1.0.32",
"@types/qs": "^6.5.1",
"@types/request": "^2.47.0",
"@types/shelljs": "^0.7.8",
"@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
"@types/winston": "^2.3.7",
"chai": "^4.1.2",
"concurrently": "^3.5.1",
"jest": "^22.0.4",
"node-sass": "^4.14.1",
"nodemon": "^1.13.0",
"shelljs": "^0.8.1",
"supertest": "^3.0.0",
"ts-jest": "^22.0.4",
"ts-node": "^5.0.0",
"tslint": "^5.9.1",
"typescript": "^2.9.1"
```

#### Tried:

- Updated @types/node to the latest version.
- Removing a froward slash from triple slashes (it started to throw more error when I did this - [You can view the errors here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyIPh.png))
- Deletion of node_modules folder and re-installation of packages

Comment: I'm also facing similar issue using typescript 2.9.1 in my angualar 6.1 project.  And I was not able to upgrade to latest typescript because angular 6.1 doesnt support anything higher than 3.0.  what errors are u getting when u upgrade greater than 2.9.1.

Comment: @user1375481 After upgrading to a higher version I'm getting the following errors. (Refer screenshot URL) https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyIPh.png

Comment: I have tried updating to angular 7 and there are new errors like yours. So im currently looking to supressing the typescript compiler error as suggested here.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861942/disable-typescript-mismatch-in-ng-packagr

Answer (score 0):

in `/// <reference> lib="esnext.asynciterable" />` the syntax actually IS invalid.

It should be `/// <reference lib="esnext.asynciterable" />` like an xml tag.

You can find more information about this by searching for "Triple-Slash Directives" in the Typescript docs.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html