# how to build a library in angular that is using another library in the same project

Tags: angular, angular-library

I am creating libraries inside a parent library as such:

-projects
  ->main-library
   ->(lib-1, lib-2)

I wish to use lib-1 inside lib-2 and then build the main-library which will in-turn contain lib-1 and lib-2.

In the lib-2.module.ts I imported the lib-1 module and tried building main-library.
The error:
  rootDir is expected to contain all source files.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850063/rootdir-is-expected-to-contain-all-source-files

Comment: I am using a modular stucture in place of using libraries using a packager to package the modules and it is running fine for the last 1 year.