# NX: Library build fails in case of sibling library as dependency

Tags: angular, build, monorepo, lib, nrwl-nx

I have an NX monorepo workspace.

I have developed a library "A" with a grouping folder to contains a bunch of different domain features "x", "y", "z" and I can build them using `nx build @A/x` (changing "x" with other subfolders).
I have also developed a library "B" with a grouping folder as well (containing "r", "s", "t" subfolders), that in turn depends on A library.

When I try to build B library I get tons of errors of this kind:

`error TS6059: File '<my-project>/libs/<A-grouping-folder>/<x-folder>/src/lib/<some-file>' is not under 'rootDir' '<my-project>/libs/<B-grouping-folder>/<r-subfolder>/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`

Here is the content of `tsconfig.base.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@A/x": ["libs/A/x/src/index.ts"],
      "@A/y": ["libs/A/y/src/index.ts"],
      "@A/z": ["libs/A/z/src/index.ts"],
      "@B/r": ["libs/B/r/src/index.ts"],
      "@B/s": ["libs/B/s/src/index.ts"],
      "@B/t": ["libs/B/t/src/index.ts"],
    },
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

In the workspace I don't have an `angular.json` file neither `workspace.json`. Both libraries have a `project.json` in their own "src/lib" folder.

I have read about this [issue](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1765), but I'm not sure is the same.
What am I doing wrong? Any idea?

Comment: Occasionally I get this if I import “directly” rather than via @ paths

Comment: It is not my case :(

Comment: A useful debugging step is to try to transpile the library using `tsc --traceResolution <library-tsconfig>`

Comment: `error TS6054: File 'libs/<A-grouping-folder>/<x-folder>/tsconfig.json' has an unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts', '.cts', '.d.cts', '.mts', '.d.mts'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation


Found 1 error.`

Comment: Sorry forgot flag, iirc `-p <path to tsconfig.json>`

Answer (score 1):

Incredibly I solved flushing node modules cache:

`rm -rf node_modules/.cache`

(Credits to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68262454/angular-monorepo-error-ts6059-file-ng-youtube-api-service-ngtypecheck-ts-is-n) came out searching with different keywords).

Comment: Happy you've solved it. It's best practice to self mark as a duplicate when you find there's already an answer on SO. This prevents answers being spread across multiple posts

Comment: Uhm, nope. I was wrong. It worked with another library that hadn't dependencies. With the case I described above I still have the issue. I am going to delete this answer, hope you are ok with it.