# NX Angular project fails build with error TS6059: File is not under 'rootDir'

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl-nx

I have an angular project inside an NX monorepo.

when I serve the app everything works, however when I build for production I get a lot of errors like the following:

```
libs/data/persistance/firebase/src/lib/data-persistance-firebase.module.ts:1:1 - 
error TS6059: File 
'C:/Users/jorda/source/repos/ng-firebase/firebase-demo/libs/data/persistance/firebase/src/lib/data-persistance-firebase.module.ngtypecheck.ts' 
is not under 'rootDir' 
'C:\Users\jorda\source\repos\ng-firebase\firebase-demo\libs\data\state\auth\src'. 
'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

I have reviewed the paths config of the workspace root tsconfig.base.json:

```json
    "paths": {
      "@fba/data/persistance/firebase": ["libs/data/persistance/firebase/src/index.ts"],
      "@fba/data/state/auth": ["libs/data/state/auth/src/index.ts"],
      "@fba/feature/auth": ["libs/feature/auth/src/index.ts"],
      "@fba/feature/feature-one": ["libs/feature/feature-one/src/index.ts"],
      "@fba/feature/feature-two": ["libs/feature/feature-two/src/index.ts"]
    },
```

but everything looks good here

As far as I can see all imports use "@fba/..." syntax when importing from another lib.

I am not sure how to debug this.

The libs all have build targets and tsconfig.ts,ng-package.json, and project.json files.

I tried:

1. removing  "rootDir": "." from tsconfig.base as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70505869/1854382)
2. removing the .cache folder from node_modules
3. remove and reinstall node_modules
4. update npm packages to most recent version
5. make sure I did not duplicate a "paths" variable in another lib's tsconfig
6. make sure there is no cirular dep between **@fba/data/persistance/firebase** and **fba/data/state/auth**

Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it turned out to be an issue when I migrated from an angular project to a nx monorepo.  The migration failed and so the config files were not properly formed, mostly the tsconfig and project.json files.

I removed and re added the NX libs and that fixed the issues for me.  It was a lot of work but it was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the cache folder within the `.nx` folder. That solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (`error TS6059: File is not under 'rootDir'`) and the issue was that the paths used for importing as defined in `tsconfig.base.json` did not match up with the `name` property in the lib's `package.json`.

Looking at your tsconfig, you use a hierarchy style naming convention:

```
@fba/data/persistance/firebase
@fba/data/state/auth
@fba/feature/auth
@fba/feature/feature-one
@fba/feature/feature-two
```

I had something similar for my paths, but when I went to update the `name` property in `package.json`, I received a VSCode warning that the name did not match a pattern:

```
String does not match the pattern of "^(?:(?:@(?:[a-z0-9-*~][a-z0-9-*._~]*)?/[a-z0-9-._~])|[a-z0-9-~])[a-z0-9-._~]*$".
```

I did some looking, and this kind of makes sense. The `@fba` suggests a scoped package, and NPM naming "rules" do not include `/` in the name of a package. Meaning, the `/` is used to separate the package's name from the scope.
[NPM package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#name)

Hope this helps.